# update route as user moves in bing maps?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I want to update the route as the device moves just like it happens in navigation. But i dont want to  use the RouteQuery and Map.AddRoute every time the position changes as given below.

```
    private void DrawRoute(GeoCoordinate newPosition)//
{
   RouteQuery query = new RouteQuery()
   {
      TravelMode = TravelMode.Driving,
      Waypoints = new List<GeoCoordinate>() { MainMap.Center, newPosition }
   };
   query.QueryCompleted += RouteQueryCompleted;
   query.QueryAsync();
   MainMap.Center = newPosition;
   lastCoordinate = newPosition;
}
```

Is there a different way?

Comment: Do it only every x seconds, or if a certain distance has been moved.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for reply,,is this the only way to update the route?